# Allocate serial number in each change in a specific column

Tags: excel, numbers, allocation, vba

I am looking for Excel VBA code, as I want to allocate serial number to the column A based on a change in Column B.  For example, I need answer in Column A as 1,2,3 for each X,Y,Z.

Can someone help to post the required VBA code?.

```
Column A     Coloum B
1             X
1             X
2             Y
2             Y
3             Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Serial()

For i = 1 To 10

 Cells(i, 2).Select

   If ActiveCell.Value = "x" Then
   Cells(i, 1) = 1

   ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "y" Then
   Cells(i, 1) = 2

   ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "z" Then
   Cells(i, 1) = 3

   End If

Next i

End Sub
```

This is the super simple version, no variables or anything of the sort.

Comment: It's highly doubtful that the vengadasamy's values are "x", "y", and "z", and it is probably not feasible for the him/her to type out every possible value.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- Your data used row 1 as a header row so actual data starts in row 2.
- The values in column B have already been sorted

Does it need to be a macro? This can be accomplished with a formula.  Put the number 1 in cell A2 and then this formula in cell A3 and copy down:

```
=A2+(B3<>B2)
```

If it has to be a macro, then something like this should work just fine:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim arrID() As Long
    Dim arrIndex As Long
    Dim lID As Long
    Dim strTemp As String

    With Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        ReDim arrID(1 To .Rows.Count)
        For Each rCell In .Cells
            If rCell.Text <> strTemp Then
                strTemp = rCell.Text
                lID = lID + 1
            End If
            arrIndex = arrIndex + 1
            arrID(arrIndex) = lID
        Next rCell
        .Offset(, -1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrID)
    End With

    Set rCell = Nothing
    Erase arrID

End Sub
```

Comment: Although I am sure it is not an issue in this case, use of `TRANSPOSE` will produce a Type Mismatch error if the number of rows exceed 65,573. This is a limitation of the function in Excel 2007 & 2010 (lower limits apply in prior versions). The need for `TRANSPOSE` can be avoided by using `ReDim arrID(1 to .Rows.Count, 1 to 1)` and then changing element reference below to `ArrID(arrIndex,1)`.